# Possible Bug in SpringMVC: Cannot handle servlet paths like / or /*

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I think I have discovered a bug in spring MVC, the JstlView does not work if the servlet path in the web xml is merely '/' or '/*' without the single quotes.  You can try it yourself, take any working web application based on spring MVC, and then adjust the dispatcher servlet path to just match '/' or '/*', and then go visit the page (with the new correct url of course) and you get a 400 error.

Here is my example, I have a spring mvc app and this is in the web xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I deploy and visit:

```
http://localhost:8080/contextroot/mvc/template
```

and the page appears perfectly fine, here are the logs:

```
21:24:05.024 [http-bio-8080-exec-92] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /template
21:24:05.048 [http-bio-8080-exec-92] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.project.www.controller.ResultController.getPersonList(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]
21:24:05.050 [http-bio-8080-exec-92] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'resultController'
21:24:05.056 [http-bio-8080-exec-92] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/contextroot/mvc/template] is: -1
21:24:05.104 [http-bio-8080-exec-92] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'template'
21:24:05.106 [http-bio-8080-exec-92] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'template'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:24:05.124 [http-bio-8080-exec-92] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'template'
21:24:05.695 [http-bio-8080-exec-92] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

so it is all working above this line, but now I change web xml like so:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I re-deploy and visit:

```
http://localhost:8080/contextroot/template
```

but I get a 400 error, here are the logs:

```
21:09:11.365 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/contextroot/template]
21:09:11.372 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /template
21:09:11.383 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.AnnaUnivResults.www.controller.ResultController.getPersonList(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]
21:09:11.384 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'resultController'
21:09:11.387 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/contextroot/template] is: -1
21:09:11.437 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'template'
21:09:11.440 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'template'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:09:11.455 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'template'
21:09:11.456 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/contextroot/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp]
21:09:11.457 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp
21:09:11.459 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp]
21:09:11.460 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/contextroot/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
21:09:11.461 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
21:09:11.464 [http-bio-8080-exec-78] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

I am pretty sure this is a bug in spring.  I wanted to post this on spring's site, but apparently the spring questions page just sends you to StackOverflow, kind of deceptive if you ask me.

I guess my question is, is this a bug?

Comment: No it isn't a bug it as a missing part of the configuration. `/*` basically means everything. Template resolution is basically a forward to a URL however the `DispatcherServlet` doesn't know how to handle a JSP. When mapping to `/*` you will need to add a `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` which basically forwards anything that cannot be handled by the `DispatcherServlet` to the default servlet which in turn will render the JSP.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by template resolution, but I will repeat that DispatcherServlet often returns a view that is a JSP, your claim that it can't handle JSP is false.

Comment: in fact, I actually used JSP in my example, that 'template' resource it gets is actually a JSP file, though you could not tell from the text.  I didn't mention it because it wasn't relevant for the question.

Comment: No it can handle views. The `DispatcherServlet` doesn't know how to render a JSP, the servlet container does however. The fact that you don't understand how the `DispatcherServlet` works doesn't mean that everyone else is wrong, and if you are setting out to blame your lack of knowledge on others please don't. Read a book and expand your knowledge instead.

Comment: @M. Deinum, it's difficult to retort when people delete my comments, I had some relevant claims there and now I can't discuss them.  I never said that the DispatcherServlet *renders* the JSP, I said it handles it.  Since the view returns JSP text, that should make its way to the container.  Hence it's a matter of semantics, the DispatcherServlet returned JSP so I say it *handled* JSP.  I would still like to know what you mean by template resolution.

Comment: It doesn't return text it returns a URL. So no it doesn't handle, render or whatever it simply constructs a URL. And actually it isn't even the `DispatcherServlet` that does that it is the `InternalResourceViewResolver` that does that. The generated URL is forwarded to, when it ends up with the `DispathcerServlet` it tries to locate a handler for it which it will not find and as such it will not render the JSP but result in the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change /* to /

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <!--url-pattern>/*</url-pattern-->
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: JFC, I spent about 8 hours trying to figure out why this was not working, and it was because of a stupid asterisk!!!  '/*' is a completely valid pattern, I stand by my statement that this is a bug in Spring MVC.  Now why the heck does spring not mention this in their documentation?  Nor does any tutorial on this topic.

Comment: and to make things worse, Spring leaves absolutely no way to contact them on their website, not a forum, not an email address, NOTHING!  I guess they are just saying "you're on your own!"

Comment: From the coderanch site I read that '/' means it's the default pattern, so if your request has an exact match, it might not go through that servlet at all, while '/*' will guarantee that your servlet is hit.  The two patterns are not the same, and both are valid in the servlet spec, spring is at fault here.  See this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/366340/Servlets/java/servlet-mapping-url-pattern

Comment: This is not a spring bug at all, this is more of a servlet api behavior - so essentially when you specify `/*` as the mapping you are saying that the Spring-servlet should handle everything, however as you can see from the error in your stacktrace it really cannot handle rendering a jsp which the container should be handling internally through a servlet(Jspservlet). When you specify `/` as the mapping instead, Spring then handles the controllers, leaving the jsp rendering to the container and so it works cleanly. So it is more of an understanding gap-no deception here.

Comment: Which is BTW also documented in a separate section of the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) guide.

Comment: The JSP file isn't rendered by the `DispatcherServlet` but by the default servlet of the servlet container. And this works flawless if you map the `DispatcherServlet` to someting other then `/*` as in that way the URL will not match the `DispatcherServlet` and it will automaticaly fallback to the default servlet. However when you map it to `/*` it matches and the `DispatcherServlet` in turn has no clue on what to do with that request. So yes my claim makes senses. Spring does support mapping to `/*` but you have to do some additional configuration (as explained in the reference guide).

Comment: you are not making any sense at all, first you say that with / it works, and then the DispatcherServlet will be the default servlet, then you say that the DispatcherServlet can't handle JSP, and that only the servlet container does.  Your words contradict themselves.

Comment: @M. Deinum, I think you need to look back at my original question and pay really close attention to what those logs say.  The DispatcherServlet got all the way to the part where it's supposed to resolve the view.  In both cases it had the same return value from the controller: "template" so the view resolver should have been able to return that text from the JSP, and then the container (Tomcat) should have been able to render it.  If you look in the logs, it's like the view resolver couldn't find that resource to return.  Either the view resolver or the servlet is what's misbehaving.

Comment: @Biju Kunjummen, your explanation doesn't make sense, you say that the container handles rendering the JSP, and that with /, the jsp rendering is left to the container.  Whether it's mapped with / or /*, the DispathcerServlet is supposed to return a view to the container, I don't see why the container would decide to render the JSP it receives from the servlet in one case but not in another.  From the logs though, it looks like the dispatcher servlet did not even provide the JSP text to the container when it was mapped with /*.

Comment: Why does the jvm take the main() method as the entry point of the application. Why won't it take start(). It's just the way it is... If you want to change it code your own servlet api

Comment: @shinjw, it's not the servlet api, I believe that if the servlet container had received the text of the JSP back from the dispatcherservlet, it could have rendered it correctly, but it didn't.

Comment: The `DispatcherServlet` or actually the `InternalResourceViewResolver` returns a URL. This URL is then forwarded to, normally this forwarded URL is picked up by the default servlet from the servlet container it sees a JSP, compiles it (if needed) and executes the resulting servlet. When the  `DispatcherServlet` sees the URL it tries to find a handler for it by consulting the  `HandlerMapping`s for the JSP there is no handler and as such it cannot handle the JSP. When adding the `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />`it will act as a catch all for everything that cannot be handled.